# PKCS12 key from Winserver2008 cert authority

Tags: windows, security, ssl, certificate

I have created a standalone cert authority in windows server 2008. I can use certreq (from that same box) to generate a cert with the appropriate CN, etc, and ensure that the private key is exportable. When I run certreq, I get the cert request file, and I can go into Certificate Authority and issue a cert by it. My problem is this: I want to make these certs for people who are no in the domain - that is, disconnected users. In order to do this, I need to give them the private and public parts of their keys. From Certificate Authority, I can export the public part in a variety of ways, and if I load the Certificate snap-in for console, I can go there and do an export of the private key...for "current user"

The problem is, I don't want it to be for the current user, I want to make it for something else entirely. What are my options here? Is there any way to make it so that Certificate Authority will export both the private and public key pair for me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really are doing this wrong. You should not be creating the private key, it isn't a **private** key when you share it.

> Is there any way to make it so that Certificate Authority will export both the private...

The certificate authority never HAS the private key.  So there is no way the CA can export both.  When certreq generates a certificate request, the **private** key is stored within the system, or user certificate store on the machine generating the request.

If you really think you must be able to generate keys+certs for people against my advice, then I suggest you use something other then certreq to generate your key+request.

If I were in your shoes I would use the OpenSSL CLI application to generate a private key and CSR, submit the CSR to the CA, from the CA sign the CSR, then retrieve the certificate, and use the OpenSSL CLI tool to build a pkcs12 file with the private key, and cert.

Comment: I think you are right that I was thinking about this wrong. I'd retract this question if I could, but long story short I am going to end up submitting the CSR's to the CA from a locally attached client machine, and then pulling the cert/keys from that client's keystore to distribute to the actual clients I need - acting as a trusted 3rd party for them.